# ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: webpack, less, create-react-app, react-app-rewired

I used "react-app-rewired" to configure "less", but there was an error after the new less file was created, and the less file did not take effect. The following is my package.json file and error message

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: I don't know how your webpack config looks. Can you [try a solution posted here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8315#issuecomment-714313936)?